# Prove or disprove $(1-y)^x(1+xy)<1$ where $x>1$, $0<y<1$.

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let$$x>1$$
$$0<y<1$$
Is it possible to prove or disprove this following:
$$(1-y)^x(1+xy)<1$$
I tested many sample results and could not find a case that make it false yet. I think Bernoulli's inequality might help.

Comment: To have symbols inline use single `$`s either side instead of double.

Comment: I believe you can use Bernoulli's inequality to get an answer here. Look it up!

Answer (score 1):

Using [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality#Generalization), 
$$(1-y)(1+xy)^{1/x}\leqslant (1-y)(1+y)=1-y^2<1$$

Raise both sides to the power $x$ to get your desired inequality.

Comment: But this changed my original inequity

Comment: You just take a power of $x$ to both sides to get the desire inequality.

Comment: @cscisgqr:   It is just the $x$ root of your original inequality.  Since we are comparing with $1$, that works because $1^{1/x}=1$